# Chances, clarification

Tags: probability, odds

What are the odds Ive met my other half?  Thing is I already know I have with this undeniable experience we had when our souls actually collided together as we were one. I just want to know what others have to say about it but without experiencing what we did here are some crazy coincidences we have in common, any comments are welcomed. Thanks in advance.

Just curious as to the odds off meeting a man unexpectedly whome I now call my soulmate.

Can you help me figure out the odds of having his daughter from another relationship sharing the same birthday as my daughter from another relationship, same month July same day 28th different year one year apart 2007and 2008 also having my son and his Nephew sharing same Birthdays, same month; June same day 5th, different year  2013 and 2018, 5 years apart. Both same sex sharing same birthdays different year. Our Mothers have the same name Debra. We both were born in 87. I was born May 1st 1987 he was born August 25 1987... we are 3 months 24 days apart in age.  I met him August 27th 2016 and he lived one block away from me even tho we had mutual friends we never crossed paths till that day when a mutual friend invited me over. Also all of our Birthdays are in sink month to month Mine May , my son and his nephew June , My daughter and his daughter in July and his in August.

Comment: There are dozens of questions of this kind on site. See the comments on the two I've indicated which discuss the futility of such post-hoc "what are the odds" style questions. You can find many more with a site search.

Comment: Also see our "[Top 10 list of reasons to close a question immediately](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3207/805)"

Comment: My specific question weren't? How rude to dismiss mine? Glen_b

Comment: 1. The point that was made in the comments I directed you to was relating to the pointlessness of attempting to answer such post-hoc *what are the chances* questions. Since this issue has been pointed out more than once on site, all new questions of this kind get closed now, as the "Top k reasons" link should have helped to make clear. 2.  It's not rudeness to apply the current policy on such questions. If you feel there's some problem with us no longer answering such questions, please raise it on our meta site, stats.meta.stackechange.com as soon as you get 5 points of reputation here.